# How can you create an instructional screen, that only appears the first time (in Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I there a simple way to route a user to a view controller only one time? This ViewController could then be an instructional screen that the user only sees once at startup.
I have this now:

```
 let skipScreen = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

@IBAction func skipButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let skipNow = true
    skipScreen.setObject(skipNow, forKey: "skip")
    skipScreen.synchronize()

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject :AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var skipNow: Bool? = skipScreen.objectForKey("skip") as Bool?


    if skipScreen.boolForKey("skip") == true{
        var nav = self.view?.rootViewController as UINavigationController
        var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        nav.pushViewController(storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookingViewController") as BookingViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

But it gives errors with the `self.window`parts and says that the viewController does not have a member named 'window'

How could I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion for creating tutorial/insturctional screens would be to create images(full screen) with opacity background color and text full visible. Handle showing with NSUserDefaults(after you show one screen, save that to user defaults so you know next time that you shouldn't show that particular image).

Don't forget to create pictures for all screens (for iphone: 4, 5, 6, 6+)

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check in your appdelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method for, lets say a boolean value in your userdefaults, which indicates wether you should start with a "instructional" viewcontroller or the normal viewcontroller.
So you can set the instrucitonal viewcontroller as the default viewcontroller in your storyboard, and you can push the "non-instructional" viewcontroller if it has been shown.

```
    if userDefaults.boolForKey("HasBeenShownInstructions") {
        var nav = self.window?.rootViewController as UINavigationController
        var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        nav.pushViewController(storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookingViewController") as BookingViewController, animated: false)
    }
```

Dont forget to save the boolean value to userdefaults when the user has dismissed/ended the instructions.

This is just one of many ways to solve the issue. You could also do it the other way around. Depends on what you need.

Comment: Ah, okay great! Do I need to use core data to do this?

Comment: I took a look into NSUserDefaults and I understand it now! I am really sorry if this question was not good (due to the -6 rating). I really had no clue how to do this and I expected that apple would have something easy like this. Therefore I wanted to ask it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added my own code, but it is not working at the moment. Do you have time to look at it for a moment? :)

Comment: Looked at it, and its not working because you are creating a new UIWindow object. Im using storyboards to create a navigationcontroller which has multiple viewcontrollers. Inside of that lives my BookingViewController as well as the InstructionsViewController. The code ive pasted in my answer should be in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not in the viewcontroller.

Comment: Oooooh, in the AppDelegate!! I am really new, so I was looking a lot in the view controller to see that. But, now I see what I can try to do. I am going to try it out. Btw, because it has -6 rating, what did I do wrong in the question? It is an interesting question right?

Comment: I don't know, I've seen worse. Some people are just prunes. But next time try to state what you have tried and exactly what you would expect/want. Im guessing it's because the question you asked was kind of "thin". Don't forget to upvote and/or mark my answer as an answer to your question if it worked. Best of luck friend!